# Tunnel http requests to another server?

Tags: web-server, http, forwarding, tunneling

I have a VPS we'll call it mydomain.com

Is it possible when someone goes to mydomain.com, the request is forwarded to another different server, let's say 192.168.0.5 processed by that server and then returned still looking like it came from mydomain.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is Proxy Pass, which are supported by both Apache and Nginx. Have a look at this page to give you an idea, http://wiki.nginx.org/LikeApache